# "The name 'n' does not exist in the current context". How can I reference a type outside of its context?

Tags: c#, types, integer

I am counting `DataTable` `rows` with `int n = dt.Rows.Count`.
Further down in my method, inside several foreach loops and whatnot, I need to reference `int n`.
I basically don't know how to do that.

> "The name 'n' does not exist in the current context"

How can I reference it outside of its context?

How my code is built up (abbreviated):

```
try {
    using (DataTable dt = new("aTableName")) {
    // more SQL stuff
    
    foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows) {

    Collection.Add(New Class {

        // adding to properties
    });
}

int n = dt.Rows.Count; /* this is the int I am trying to reference */
```

further down I instantiate a list of the collection, and iterate through with a foreach loop. It's within that foreach loop that I need to reference the int.
Can it be done?

Comment: We won't know how to make the changes to your existing code base without seeing your original code. Please post a [mre], and fully explain what needs to be modified.

Comment: can you post some of your code? generally, declare the int n variable in the scope above the loops.

Comment: The naming scope of a variable is controlled by curly bracket nesting. Have a look at how many levels of curly brackets it's in by, to see where to declare `n`.

Comment: I have added some code to give context as I try to investigate your comments. Thank you

Comment: I can't declare the int further up the hierarchy

Comment: "...further down i instantiate..." - down in same method or other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use variable both inside and outside of loop scope you should declare it outside of your loop:

- in method as `variable`;
- in class as `field` or `property`;

Example with declaring `n` variable in **method scope**:

```
static void RowDeleter()
{
    // Creating DataTable with 3 rows
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Rows.Add(dt.NewRow());
    dt.Rows.Add(dt.NewRow());
    dt.Rows.Add(dt.NewRow());

    // Declaring 'n' variable outside of loop scope and inside method scope
    int n = dt.Rows.Count;
    Console.WriteLine("Initial row count: " + n); // 3

    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().ToArray())
    { 
        // Deleting each row from DataTable
        dt.Rows.Remove(row);
        // Updating variable value with current row count
        n = dt.Rows.Count;
    }
  
    // Displaying result
    Console.WriteLine("Remained rows count: " + n); // 0
}
```

Example with declaring `n` variable in **class scope** as `field`:

```
class RowClass
{
    // Declaring variable in class scope, outside of method and loop scopes
    private static int n;

    private static void RowDeleter()
    {
        // Creating DataTable with 3 rows same as upper...

        // Assigning value to 'N' property which is outside of method scope
        n = dt.Rows.Count; // No 'int N' again, we just accessing to it
        Console.WriteLine("Initial row count: " + n); // 3

        foreach (...)
        {  
            // Same as upper
            n = dt.Rows.Count;
        }

        // Same displaying result
        Console.WriteLine("Remained rows count: " + n); // 0
    }
}
```

Example with declaring `n` variable in **class scope** as `property`:

```
class RowClass
{
    private static int N { get; set; }

    private static void RowDeleter()
    {
        // Creating DataTable with 3 rows same as upper...

        // Assigning value to 'n' variable which is outside of method scope
        N = dt.Rows.Count; // No 'int n'. Variable already declared, we just accessing to it
        Console.WriteLine("Initial row count: " + N); // 3

        foreach (...)
        {  
            // Same as upper
            N = dt.Rows.Count;
        }

        // Same displaying result
        Console.WriteLine("Remained rows count: " + N); // 0
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally, the variable is valid in the context it is declared at. If you declare int n in a function, you cannot access it outside that function.

If you need a function to be accessable from outside, you have a few options:

**1- Use a higher-context** (e.g. declare the variable somewhere common to both functions). If you have your context deeper in a function (e.g. inside an if statement, for-loop, etc,..) then this is what you need to do.

```
int n;

public int modifyingFunction() {
...
   n = 5;
}
public int usingFunction() {
   someFunction(n);
}
```

**2- Use a public declaration with referencing parameters**. By doing so and having the correct reference to the instance of wherever you declared your variable at (assuming you declared it in, say, a class) this would only work for such cases where your value is stored in a seperate object, with its own instance

```
public class myClass
{
    public int n;

    public myClass()
    {
        n = 25;
    }
}
class mainClass
{
    static void Main()
    {
        myClass c = new myClass();
        Console.WriteLine(c.n);
    }
}
```

**3- Return the value of n from the function**, or use it to the call another function. This is the case if you have a value that's inside another function.

```
public int myFunction() {
   n = 25;
   .
   .
   return n;
}
```

or

```
         static void Main(string[] args)
         {
             int x = 10;
             Multiplication(ref x);
         }
         public static void Multiplication(ref int a)
         {
              a *= a;
         }
     }
```

Example taken from [here](https://www.tutlane.com/tutorial/csharp/csharp-pass-by-reference-ref-with-examples)

Note that the first returns the value, while the 2nd method returns a reference to the variable.

Comment: Will you please elaborate your points with simply examples? I also updated my question. thank you

Comment: @Sandra Updated answer. Let me know if anything is unclear